# Corrupting CRC field of a CAN message in CAPL

Tags: security, can-bus, capl, canoe, fuzzing

I want to add some anomalies to corrupt the CRC field of the CAN message. Theoretically, the CRC is being calculated using the info from data field/ctrl field/ ARB field. How to add the CRC corruption in the CAN message?

Comment: Would be helpful to know which tool you want to use to send your CAN message

Comment: You cannot do this in higher layer software since the CRC is already checked by the CAN controller before it goes there. So you'd have to do this on the hardware level. Basically: make a MCU that sends a CAN message then x time units into the frame, let some input capture timer trigger on a flank, toggle some BJT that pulls the line to the wrong level during 1 bit length. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? You don't trust the CAN controllers sold in millions on pcs to do their job?

Comment: Basically, our motive is to create corruption in the CRC level of a message. All the other part of the message will be valid. We want to see how the ECU will respond upon getting this error messages.

Comment: We are using CAN1640A and CANoe config.

Comment: However, I want to check it on Software level using CAPL. From your comment I believe, it is only possible in hardware level.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is possible doing this with CANoe, however you need a different piece of hardware.

Vector calls this *CAN disturbance*.

If you search for disturbance on their page, you will get to the product.

Also search for *disturbance* in CANoe's documentation. With the hardware aforementioned, you can basically inject errors in every part of the CAN frame.